# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\Bigg(1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}\Bigg)\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I wanna use here Cauchy-Maclaurin test .

So, now \begin{align*}
& \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{\ln(n+1) (2x-1)} dx \\
=\ & \left. \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} \frac{1}{2} \ln(2x-1)\right|_{1}^{n}\\
=\ & \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} \frac{1}{2} \ln(2n-1)
\end{align*}
Now the rest part can be done easily.

But, is my process correct? I doubt because there is $n$ term i.e. $\ln(n+1)$ in each term in that series ,  so, can we apply Cauchy Maclaurin test in this

Also, what about others like $$\Bigg(\frac{1}{n^{2}+1}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{1}{n^{2}+n}\Bigg).$$Can we apply Cauchy Maclaurin test as using above.

That means, can we write $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^{2}+x} dx $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it precise by observing that $\int_1^{n} \frac 1 {2x-1}dx$ lies between  $1+\frac 1  3+...+\frac 1 {2n-1}$  and $\frac 1  3+\frac  1 5+...+\frac 1 {2n+1}$. Note that when you divide by $\ln {(n+1)}$ and take the limit the terms $1$ and $\frac 1 {2n+1}$ don't contribute anything. Hence the answer you got is correct.

You can use the same type of argument in the secons case also , so your integral does give the answer.

Comment: What about the next one?

Comment: So, the integration I wrote for the second one,,,is also correct??

Comment: But ,,for the first one,,, you use sandwich,,so, what about the second one,,,we use ,,for telling that prop. is correct?

Comment: @Alearner I am sorry for  the confusion. The second case also works the same way.